# Are there sources of noise in qubits for which the fundamental origin is unknown?

Tags: resource-request, noise

I am looking for examples of sources of noise in qubits for which the fundamental origin is unknown. I.e. we see experimentally that the qubits are noisy, but we do not really understand why they are "that much" noisy (the theory predicts less noise for instance). I insist on the "fundamental origin" aspect. For instance things like crosstalk do not enter in the category because perhaps we don't have a good model to understand it quantitatively, when many qubits are in the computer but this is rather a "practical" aspect of modelling.

One example I can give in superconducting qubit is the presence of more quasiparticles than what the theory predicts at the qubit's temperature being 10mK. It makes the qubit noisy. See [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-34727-2). We still don't understand why there are so many quasiparticles.

I am looking for references to papers clearly saying that this is an open question of the community.

Comment: We do not know where most of the errors are coming from, it is mostly stray fields from all kind of external interactions, we just know how to characterize them and sometimes we can correct/mitigate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLS in superconducting qubits.

When you vary the frequency of a superconducting qubit and plot the T1 lifetime you see huge dips in the lifetime at certain frequencies. The dips aren't static; they come and go and drift around over time. [Here's a recent talk showing some of them respond to strain and to electric fields](http://video.ictp.it/WEB/2024/2024_01_15-smr3916/2024_01_15-11_00-smr3916.mp4):

> [image]

The dips are called "TLS"s which is short for "Two Level System" which is another way of saying "Qubit". And that's actually quite appropriate. In fact, in some cases historically [a TLS was a better qubit than the actual qubit](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys972)!

So superconducting qubits have these unwanted parasitic qubits wandering around their frequency space. No one knows exactly what a TLS is physically, though there's a bunch of guesses. Probably there's many different types. More importantly, no one knows how to get rid of them. Mostly we just avoid touching them.